# Аутентификация в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

Разбираюсь с Spring Security(и параллельно пишу веб приложение). Всё работает, но есть пара вопросов..

Моя конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ua")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    SecurityUserDetailsService securityUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/records").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(securityUserDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

Контроллер для кастомной логин формы:

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }
}
```

И форма на вьюшке login.jsp

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formLoginId" action="<c:url value='/login'/>" method="POST">
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <strong>Error!</strong> Invalid username or password..
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="login">Login:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Enter login">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn col-md-offset-10">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Из того, что я понял, это когда мы обращаемся к какому-то защищенному ресурсу (например /records), срабатывает вот это строчка

```
.loginPage("/login")
```

и меня перенаправляет в контроллер

```
login()
```

с url

```
/login
```

который в свою очередь отправляет меня на вьюшку `/login.jsp`.
На этой вьюшке в форме я заполняю инпуты с именами username и password и отправляю их опять на /login методом POST... И вот здесь мне не понятно, какой именно контроллер это отлавливает? Если всё тот же `/login`, то там метод GET, да и параметры он никакие не принимает (username, password). И откуда на вьюшке берётся переменная `${param.error}`? Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим, и если что-то в моих рассуждениях не верно, то поправьте. Спасибо.

Comment: Spring Security регистрирует фильтр, который перехватывает все запросы к адресу, определённому в конфигурации как `loginPage`. Он же устанавливает `${param.error}`.

Answer (score 0):

`param.error` ты получишь в случае неудачной авторизации или же если данные не прошли валидацию.
Форма же должна выглядеть примерно так:

```html
<body>
  <form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Где `/j_spring_security_check` это дефолтный spring-security URL для обработки данных авторизации.

Но если хочется как то изменить стандартный механизм авторизации можно переопределить `login-processing-url`.
В примере выше что бы он работа в конфигурации надо добавить login-processing-url, который и будет указывать на ваш `action : "/login"`

Можешь заглянуть ко мне на Github и посмотреть как там это реализовано: [SecurityConfig.java](https://github.com/gvart/Bookmarks/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/gva/bookmarks/config/SecurityConfig.java)

Comment: Я понимаю почему я получаю param.error, я не понимаю откуда я его получаю. Что значит "дефолтный spring-security URL для обработки данных авторизации"? Где спринговский контроллер который обрабатывает этот запрос? По поводу вашего проекта на гитхабе, какой контроллер обрабатывает .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")? Не могу найти его..

Comment: Для этого нету котроллера, контейнер спринга сам понимает что надо обрабатывать. Если тебе надо это как то сделать по своему для  этого создаеться сервис который это обрабатывает. Пример : https://github.com/gvart/Bookmarks/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/gva/bookmarks/service/AuthenticationService.java . `/j_spring_security_check` стандартный URL где спринг будет ждать user - password.

Comment: Как спринг связывает строчку loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") с методом boolean autoLogin(String username, String password) и с AuthenticationService  сервисом в частности?

Comment: Точнее как связывает с сервисом понятно (вот так: auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());), но как он связывает loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") с методом boolean autoLogin(String username, String password) не пойму..